# Android prevent saving state

Tags: android, orientation, state

how can I disable saving widget's state from a class that extends specific widget? I need it to behave just like it was newly created.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way to prevent *any* `View` to persist its state is to not assign id to this view (i.e. no `android:id="..."`).

---

If that is no sufficient and you still need to reference the view, you can use next trick. Override `View`'s [`onSaveInstanceState()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSaveInstanceState%28%29) and [`onRestoreInstanceState()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onRestoreInstanceState%28android.os.Parcelable%29) in a following way:

```
@Override
public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState()
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState();
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state)
{
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(null);
}
```

Comment: Those 2 functions are public, not protected. I've already tried overriding onRestoreInstanceState before. It crashes and the logcat says that's because I didn't call the super function. Anyway, what should I return in onSaveInstance state?

Comment: I've copied function prototypes from documentation, and they were protected there. But you're right, they are public. Also I've updated the answer and now I tested it, it should work. Sorry for misleading the first time.